# Application of Ulam Lemma

Tags: measure-theory, compactness

I can’t understand how to derive the following conclusion from

> **Lemma** (Ulam) 
>   Let $(X, \tau)$ be a Polish space and $\mu$ a positive finite Borel measure on $X$. Then for every $\epsilon >0 $ there exists a compact set $K =K(\epsilon) \subset X$ s.t. $ \mu(X \setminus K) < \epsilon$

Then I have the following remark:

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete separable metric space and let $\mu$ be a probability on $X$. Let $A \subset X$ be a Borel set s.t. $\mu( X \setminus A) = 0 $.
Then $A$ is $\sigma$ compact.

For me $\sigma$ compact means being the union of (at most) countable compact sets.

How can it be true? Even if the statement is not precise and it means

> there exists a family $\{ K_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of compact set each one contained in $A$ s.t. 
>   $$ \mu ( A \setminus \bigcup_n K_n) =0 $$

how can I prove it?

I know I can take (thanks to Ulam lemma) a sequence of compact sets $C_n$ s.t. $\mu(X \setminus C_n ) = \mu( A \setminus C_n) <1/n$ and take $$K_n := \bigcup_{k=1}^n C_k$$

Then the $K_n$ are compact sets and
$$ \mu ( A \setminus \bigcup_n K_n) =0 $$

But they are not contained in $A$. Maybe I can take $Q_n = C_n \cap A$ but now they are not compact any more. Unless $A$ is closed (and it is in the case $A= \text{supp} \mu$).

Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh you mean a separable metric space.

Comment: I can’t understand your comment.

Comment: Is $A$ measurable? If $A$ is Borel, then this follows from the inner regularity of Borel measures.

Comment: Yes $A$ is measurable. Can you expand your comment?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you said. My measure is only a sigma additive function from the borel sets of $X$ info $(0,+\infty)$. I do not have any regularity property.

Comment: What if $A$ is not a Borel set?

Comment: $A$ is a Borel set. I edited the question. I’m sorry that it wasn’t clear.

Comment: Since $\mu$ is finite and, thus, tight, for any Borel set $A$:
$$
\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(K): K\subset A, K \text{ compact}\}.
$$

Comment: Uh I see, I did’t know that all finite positive Borel measures are tight. Thank you!

Comment: This is your first lemma.

Comment: In the Lemma I just see that $X$ can be approximated by compact sets, not every Borel measurable set. Is the tightness a direct consequence of it?

Comment: In any case, here $\sigma$ compact doesen’t mean being the countable union of compact set, but being the countable union of compact set plus a zero measure set. Right?

Comment: This is the definition of tightness: for each $\epsilon$, there exists a compact set s.t. $\mu(X\setminus K_{\epsilon})<\epsilon$. The inner regularity of Borel measures follows from tightness.

Comment: Ok, I’m sorry. I taught you meant “inner regular” with “tight”. How can I prove tightness implies inner regularity?

Comment: See e.g. Section 2 in https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/jancol1.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! And about the use of the term $\sigma$ compact, what do you say?